# Skip a line when using with..open

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am reading a large text file line by line

```
import re

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(regex stuff, line):
            #skip next line
```

I would like to skip a line if I find a match - how can I do this using `with...open` statement?

Comment: Are you trying to do something when line doesn't match?

Comment: The other way around. When it matches I'm trying to read the next line.

Comment: Actually reading my OP it should be 'skip to next line' -not- to 'skip a line'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `next` on the original file-like obj `f`.

```
import re

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(regex, line):
            next_line = next(f, '')
```

This will put the contents of the following line in `next_line` or if you matched on the last line of the file, it'll be an empty string. Do something with `next_line` if you want. When the `for`-loop resumes it will be from the line following that one...

Answer (score 2):

You condition should be `if not search(regex stuff,line)`

```
import re

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not re.search(regex stuff, line):
            continue # or do something
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need some state. I'll call that state `skipnext`:

```
import re

skipnext = False

with open("file.txt") as f:
 if skipnext:
  skipnext = False
  continue
 for line in f:
  if re.search(regex stuff, line):
   skipnext = True
```